# Not able to read data from SocketChannel

Tags: java, android, sockets, sslsocketfactory

We have a server with https and which runs on port 443. I want to read bytes form server.
I am using following code.

```
private void openAndConfigureChannel(Selector sel) throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory factory =
                (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket sslSocket =
                (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(address,port);

        sslSocket.startHandshake();
        SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open();
        channel.connect(sslSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        channel.configureBlocking(false);

        TCLog.i(TAG,"channel:"+channel);

        //channel.configureBlocking(false);
        channel.register(sel, channel.validOps());
    }
```

and while reading data

```
private byte[] readData(SelectionKey key) throws Exception {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        buf.clear();
        if (socketChannel .read(buf) == -1) {
            socketChannel .close();
            Log.i(TAG, "Error during read operation");
        }
        buf.flip();
        byte[] array = buf.array();
        int toPosition = buf.limit();
        byte[] subarray = ArrayUtils.subarray(array, 0, toPosition);
        return subarray;
    }
```

It gives me exception as `Connection reset by peer`. On line `socketChannel .read()`.

Event I have tried with `InetSocketAddress` but still no luck
Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. You already have an `SSLSocket`, from which you are getting an IP address and port to connect a plaintext socket channel to, even though it is practically certain that the peer will be speaking SSL, not plaintext. What exactly was wrong with using the original `SSLSocket`?

Comment: @EJP: So do you have any solutions over it? I have tried various ways but didn't find any solution. If you have any solution will be really helpful.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Why aren't you using the SSLSocket to do your reading and writing?

Comment: Do I have any solutions for *what*? You can't talk plaintext to an SSL peer. You shouldn't waste two connections per client. Client-side NIO is basically pointless, and NIO wih SSL requires using the `SSLEngine`, which is not for the faint-hearted. Use the `SSLSocket`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP: Thank you for your valuable reply, I will try with `SSLEngine`, If any problem comes, I will update the question with `SSLEngine` please guide me.

Comment: Why? You already have the `SSLSocket`. Just communicate with that. If you insist on using a `SocketChannel` and `SSLEngine`, get rid of the `SSLSocket`. You are wasting server resources.

Comment: Yes I got rid of `SSLSocket` and now I am using `SSLEngine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Followed [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLENG) link. And suggestion given by [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp).

Now I am able to connect and read data.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very useful :)

Comment: You have 'followed the suggestion given by EJP' how?